# Android is deleting downloaded audio files from internal storage

Tags: java, android, storage

I have an application that downloads and stores some small audio files on internal storage.
Some of users are reporting that files were deleted and application asks for download them again.

The problem wasn't solved with disabling Automatic optimization of android.

Comment: Then try external storage.

Comment: The only option is to rename downloaded file in internal storage. Else download files in external directory.